No root user encountered an error installing glibc2.18 on centos7
Since I don't have administrator privileges, I tried to install glibc2.18 in centos 7, compiling the source code. when I configure it, REPORT a warning
configure: WARNING:
*** These auxiliary programs are missing or incompatible versions: autoconf
*** some features will be disabled.
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.

I have confirmed that the autoconf version is 2.72, which is higher than the required version 2.56.
After I successfully make and make install, I add glibc to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH={MyPath}/glibc-2.18/lib

But my ldd is not working,when i typeldd --version it says Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I would like to know if this has anything to do with my autoconf version, and how I can install glibc 2.18 properly.


After I successfully make and make install, I add glibc to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

That will not end well. The most likely outcome is that your programs (with that LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting) will crash at startup or fail with other mysterious symbol resolution errors.
See this answer for details.
